# Excel Interop crashes excel each time it is used

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am having a rather annoying problem using excel interop in my project. The project is a small program to take all excel files in a folder, and print them all out as one print job. The way im doing this is converting the xls files to pdf, and then merging that pdf into one pdf file. Now the issue is, that whenever i convert the xls file to pdf. I get a popup window saying that excel has stopped working. [image]

This does not happend if i put a long thread sleep timer after the convertion. here is the code:

```
private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var files = new DirectoryInfo(textBox1.Text).GetFiles("*.xls")                   

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            ExportWorkbookToPDF(file.FullName,
                textBox1.Text + $@"\{pdfFolder}\" + file.Name.Remove(file.Name.Length - 4));
        }
    }


 private static void ExportWorkbookToPDF(string workbook, string output)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(workbook) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Cannot create PDF copy " +
                "from empty workbook.");
        }

        var excelApplication = new Application();
        excelApplication.ScreenUpdating = false;
        excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;
        excelApplication.Visible = false;

        Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(workbook);

        if (excelWorkbook == null)
        {
            excelApplication.Quit();
            excelApplication = null;
            excelWorkbook = null;

            throw new NullReferenceException("Cannot create new excel workbook.");
        }

        try
        {
            excelWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,
                output);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            excelWorkbook.Close();
            excelApplication.Quit();
            excelApplication = null;
            excelWorkbook = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Verify your **Taskmanager-Processes** for any running excel instance even after closing.

Comment: They all close properly. and the function works as intended, it converts all the xls to pdf.

Comment: I have verified the same logic and am able to see the EXCEL is still running in **Processes** of Task Manager

Comment: well. this does not really help me with my problem